# DisplayPort KVM

Tags: kvm-switch, connection, display

I need to hook up two machines, each with dual DisplayPort monitors, to a KVM.  I'd ideally like to switch via hotkey.  I've tried the StarTech KVM switch, but it fails with a 30" display 2560x1600 (despite being advertised that it can).  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

The Startech KVM SV231DPDDUA will display 2560x1600. We had discovered compatibility issues with some monitors last year (2011) which has since been fixed. This KVM has been tested with Dell U3008, and the Dell U3011 at 2560x1600 resolutions. If you are still in possession of the KVM, I encourage you to return it for a free replacement with the fix in place.